# How to Displaying Html in Webview in android without delay

Tags: android, html, webview

I am developing a hybrid application which an activity has webview and i will load html from assets folder as shown below.

but, when i start that activity from other activity , it initially displays a white screen (about 2-3 seconds) and then loads the html in webView.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

    WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

        webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.select_passenger);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

    }
}
```

kindly advice me how to overcome this delay without displaying any progress bar.

Thanks & Regards.

Nagendra.

Comment: `2-3` Seconds is more....then you'll post this as an Bug to `Google Android Community`.....

Comment: Still didn't found the solution, excpet for using progress dialog, do we need to use progress dialog to load the html ,javascript and css which are available locally.